# How change arm's torrc path?

Tags: configuration, nyx

Default arm's torrc path is `~/.arm/torrc`, how can a change it to `/etc/tor/torrc`? I has searched in arm's documentation but can not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Arm was renamed to `nyx` and the [development continued](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git) - nowdays there's no need in torrc, only control protocol is used. add to your nyx this argument:

- [--interface [tor control address]:[tor control port]](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/tree/nyx/arguments.py#n84) if you're using TCP/IP for control protocol
- [--socket /path/to/socket](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/tree/nyx/arguments.py#n99) if you're using a socket

The config path in command line arguments is a config for nyx, not for tor. Default one is looked for at `~/.nyx/config` file

And see the full list of config args in the [sample nyxrc provided by the developers](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/tree/web/nyxrc.sample)

Comment: Why is nyx not on torproject home page? Why do projects like whonix still use the arm as controller tor? There is little reference to nyx on the internet, so it's harder to work with.

Comment: I checked the latest released versions and got the following result:

nyx version 1.4.6-dev (released April 28, 2011). 

arm version 1.4.5.0 (released April 28, 2012)

It seems that the latest version of the arm was released after the last version of nyx. I dont understand.

Comment: Take a look at torproject.org - there's a link for Arm, yes, pointing at https://www.atagar.com/arm/ - but there git repo and binary name has changed to nyx. It's confusing, I know - but here https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/ is where it all resides, last update less than 2 days from now

Answer (score 0):

As it was already written in Alexeys answer Tor arm has a new name: [nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/)

When you want to use another configuration file, you can use the following line:

```
nyx --config /path/to/config
```

However using `/etc/tor/torrc` or any other `torrc` will not work. Tor uses a different set of options than nyx.